# problems with google map markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

as you can see at my [test.php](http://myrange.de/support/map/test.php) the marker ist working fine.
but when I zoom the map for an better overview the marker is going to north???
If I zoom a lot, the marker moved to North sea :-(
Is this a known bug? or am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MyRange Driving Ranges world wide </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />

<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 30px; padding: 0px }
#map_canvas { height: 80% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.1601369818597, 6.72036588191986);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var image = 'images/flag_red_big.png';

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.1601369818597, 6.72036588191986);
var golfMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map, icon: image });

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div align="center" id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [anchor point for an icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) (which is what you get if you don't define it) is at the bottom center of the image.

You need to fully specify the icon using an instance of [MarkerImage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage).

FYI - your icon seems to move because there is a lot of empty space between the bottom of the flag and the bottom of the image (which is where it is currently anchored).

Comment: wow very fast answer. thank you very much 

I do not realy need an own image for my marker, but I do not know how to use a google-map-flag for my marker :-(

Comment: I've seen it many times before.  I don't understand your comment.  If you don't need a custom icon, don't use one, the default icon will work for you.  If you want to use the icon you have, you need to determine where you want it anchored (the bottom of the staff of the flagpole is the normal place), then define the MarkerImage object correctly.

Comment: thank you. sometimes it is simple. "If you don't need a custom icon, don't use one, the default icon will work for you." Now it works fine :-)