# Polyline custom clickable markers centered

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have this Google example code here, http://jsbin.com/EpujIcU/2/edit?js,output which is a polyline "route" with two normal markers along the route:

[image]

What I really would like is if I can tweak the marker, so it looks a lot nicer (small circle) - fx. like this picture:

[image: My own drawing of what I would like]

The custom markers should still be clickable so I can put an info window to it.

I do know of the possibility of custom markers, but it doesn't place the marker in the middle of the line but instead in top (yes, my icon is badly draw):

[image]

Is it possible to get as I want in the middle picture?

Comment: hat does your code look like?   How big is the marker?

Comment: The icon is 25x25 px - I am just using my own icon instead of the standard marker. Just type in `icon:"http://url/icon.png"` in the marker section.

Comment: You have to specify the anchor correctly.  It defaults to the bottom center if you don't set it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems with google map markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970259/problems-with-google-map-markers) (although this answer uses the deprecated MarkerImage class, that has been replaced by [google.maps.Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to configure the anchor custom [icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) correctly.

```
icon: {url: "http://url/icon/png", anchor: new google.maps.Point(12,12)}
```